# Is there a way to create a link to a corollary/theorem/proposition inside a proof?

Tags: cross-referencing, links

I want to create a link inside a proof about a previous result. In the sense that if I change the number of the result (like corollary 1.2 to corollay 2.5) then I don't have to do it manually inside the proof and hence the corollary reference number changes automatically to its new number.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  There shouldn't be any problem attaching a `\label` to the (autommatically numbered) corollary, and then including `\ref{<corollary label>}` in the text of the proof.  The job will have to be run twice to resolve the reference.

Comment: @barbarabeeton it worked! thank you so much! greets from Spain